# Javascript/Appscript : Looping to nested Arrays to separate string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to remove the days on the first index of the nested array.

The first index is consists of the **name** and the **day**. How could I separate the **name** and **day** and then I would like to put the **day** on the 2nd index of the array.

Also, names could be more than 2 words

**Code:**

```
let days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

let nestedArray = [
  ['Joe Smith Monday", "07/26/2021", True, 34],
  ['John Smith Tuesday", "07/26/2021", True, 34],
  ['Sarah Smith Wednesday", "07/26/2021", True, 34],
  ['Arthur Smith Thursday", "07/26/2021", True, 34],
  ['Karen Smith Friday", "07/26/2021", True, 34],
  ['Jody Smith Saturday", "07/26/2021", True, 34],
];
```

**The Output:**

```
[
  ["Joe Smith, "Monday", "07/26/2021", True, 34],
  ["John Smith, "Tuesday", "07/26/2021", True, 34],
  ["Sarah Jessica Smith", "Wednesday", "07/26/2021", True, 34],
  ["Arthur Smith", "Thursday", "07/26/2021", True, 34],
  ["Karen Smith", Friday", "07/26/2021", True, 34],
  ["Jody Smith", "Saturday", "07/26/2021", True, 34],
];
```

Would like to know what would be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need the `days` array. This code is short, clean and it works :)

```js
let nestedArray = [
  ['Joe Smith Monday', '07/26/2021', true, 34],
  ['John Smith Tuesday', '07/26/2021', true, 34],
  ['Sarah Smith Wednesday', '07/26/2021', true, 34],
  ['Arthur Smith Thursday', '07/26/2021', true, 34],
  ['Karen Smith Friday', '07/26/2021', true, 34],
  ['Jody Smith Saturday', '07/26/2021', true, 34],
];

const newNestedArray = nestedArray.map(
  row => /^([\w ]+) +(\w+)$/i.test(row.shift()) && [RegExp.$1, RegExp.$2, ...row]
);

console.log(newNestedArray);
```

Let me know if this helps.

P.S. Edited to make it a cool one-liner :)

Answer (score 0):

### Here you go

```js
let days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
    "Saturday", "Sunday"];

let nestedArray = [
            ["Joe Smith karen Monday", "07/26/2021", "True", 34],
            ["John Smith Tuesday", "07/26/2021", "True", 34],
            ["Sarah Smith Wednesday", "07/26/2021", "True", 34],
            ["Arthur Smith Thursday", "07/26/2021", "True", 34],
            ["Karen Smith Friday", "07/26/2021", "True", 34],
            ["Jody Smith Saturday", "07/26/2021", "True", 34],
    ];
let str = "";
let day_from_str = "";
for (j in nestedArray) {
   str = nestedArray[j][0];
   for (day in days) {
          let ind = str.indexOf(days[day]);
          if (ind != -1) {
              day_from_str = str.slice(ind);
              name_from_str = str.slice(0, ind - 1);
              nestedArray[j].shift(str);
              nestedArray[j].unshift(day_from_str);
              nestedArray[j].unshift(name_from_str);
              break;
  }
  }
}
```